# Primitive recursive function for $\left[\frac{x}{2}\right] = max\{z ∈ N0 \ | \ 2 · z ≤ x\} $

Tags: computer-science

I need to find a primitive recursive function for

$t(x) = \left[\frac{x}{2}\right] = max\{z \in \  N0 \ | \  2 · z ≤ x\}$

Unfortunately whatever I come up with isn't primitive recursive. I have also tried "splitting" this but that didn't help me either. A hint in the right direction is highly appreciated!

Comment: Informally, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=0$, $f(n)=f(n-2)+1$ for $n>1$.

Comment: I got so far aswell, but a primitive function is always f(n-1) as far as I know, so the issue there is the f(n-2) where I am stuck.